# adding value to a list via session in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

in my page1.aspx.cs I have this

```
  resultsHtml.Append("<a class='btn btn-warning' href='report.aspx?asset=" + rd["n_asset_id"].ToString() + "'><i class='fa fa-paw'></i></a> ");
```

so in my report.aspx I will catch the value.

```
Session["passThis"] = Request.QueryString["asset"];
```

However in my action.cs I created a class that will store the list. I'm thinking of adding a session there but everytime i will the `store()` it will just create another List.

```
public static void store() {

    List<string> ast = new List<string>();

}
```

How can I achieve this feat? I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: its because within your `store()` method you are creating a new list instead of adding data to an already created list, declare your list outside of the method and within the method set/get your session data.

Comment: I've think of that but how can I add the data to the list if it's outside, I believe it will throw an error because there is no variable such as the declared List? It's been 2 days and google can't answer

Comment: Put your declared list declaration before the method definition start.

Comment: In your store function first you can get the value from session (which is list considerably as you mentioned) and then you can add more values to list. After that you can reassign the updated list into session variable. Hope this will resolve your problem. If not, then please provide details with exact output that you want from scenario given by you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the best approach would be to extract assets list into property (so you can easily access it from other parts of code. In property getter, code checks if there's list in session.

In `Store` method you're accessing List of assets (`List<string`) and, if there is `asset` parameter in current Request, adds it to your list of assets. Notice that accessing `Session` is done through `HttpContext.Current.Session` because of `static` metod/property.

```
public static void Store()
{
    string assetValue = HttpContext.Current.Request["asset"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(assetValue))
        AssestsList.Add(assetValue);


}

public static List<string> AssestsList
{
    get
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["assets"] == null)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["assets"] = new List<string>();
        }

        return HttpContext.Current.Session["assets"] as List<string>;
    }
    set
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["assets"] = value;
    }
}
```

so, to use this, just call `Store()` from your code.

If you have some questions, feel free to ask.